# redux store state between page route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

setup:

> - @page1 loads list of items
> - @page1 i have a link to route to @page2
> - @page2 have dropdown list with items from @page1 via redux store/connect

works **route> @page1 -> @page2**

> it works ok if the flow goes @page1 -> @page2 since it ensures items to be preloaded.

question how to be **route -> @page2**

> but what is the best way to handle items when it directly goes to @page2 , should i somehow detect the route origin and load items @page2 again?

Comment: You can easily check if the data exists in `redux store`, If it does render the page and if doesn't, request the data first and then render the component. It doesn't matter which page you're on. You can also make use of middlewares.

Comment: __upvote__ for mentioning middlewares

Comment: @random-user could you please a bit elaborate. i face the wall again while i was trying to implement your suggestion.to create something like generic via middleware, entails me to have all actions referencable within my middle ware. since it gonna be dynamic. is it possible with with dispatching(actiontype) to invoke action. so far i was only calling directly function/action itself once i get it through connect()

Comment: Can you upload the code of your components so we can take a look at it and see your implementation., `entails me to have all actions referencable within my middle ware` why all actions, For this you can have simple middleware that checks if the data is loaded or not and  load if not already loaded. ,and that's all its functionality should be.

Comment: ` const ensure=({ dispatch, getState}) => next => action =>{
     if(action.type.substring(0, 7) == 'ENSURE_'){
}`

Comment: I meant entire code, Are you creating components using `react component class` or `stateless functional components`?

Comment: something like this. want to have something generic, hence its middleware 

` const ensure=({ dispatch, getState}) => next => action =>{ 
    if(action.type.substring(0, 7) == 'ENSURE_'){
        //here i have to dispatch the corresponding action which resides in other component 
       // say if my  actiontype is ENSURE_USERS_LOAD_SUCCESS
       // i want to do this  trigger like dispatch(usersLoad()) or dispatch({ type: USERS_LOAD})
}
}`

Comment: .sorry at the moment the entire code is not under my hands

i use mix of it, but particular component which makes loadUsers() in componentDidMount()  so its  react class Component.  i end up triggering sequence of dispatch(loadUsers) within actionCreator fetchUser() itself using thunk-redux, though looks not nice. since i am calling actions from other component

Comment: I commented on your gist, I will add middlewares example for you but tomorrow.

Comment: yeah, you are correct that was my initial approach to put inside my selectors, then with your middleware idea i start pursuing some generic solution.  but i was doing with redux middleware

Answer (score 0):

How are the items from page 1 being populated?

If I'm understanding your question correctly you shouldn't need to worry about how to handle the items since they are stored in your redux store.

When you do a `mapStateToProps` you can define what data from the store you want available to the page 2 component.

Comment: correct, if use case first go to @page1 and then to @page2 items will be available @store to @page2 via `mapStateToProps` function. 

however concern is what if use case to route to @page2 directly, since `loadItems action` get triggered from @page1, what is the optimal way of handling such data dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, This example showcases how to achieve this using `Component` and `Actions`

You can have your **reducer** setup like this

```
const app_default_data = {
    items: [],
    loaded: false,
}
function appReducer(app=app_default_data, action) {
    // your ap preducer code here.
    return app;
}
export default appReducer;
```

Your **action** can look like this

```
// your loadAppData action will load data from server
const loadAppData = () => {
    // load the data from server
    // validate it
    // save data in your store.
    // change loaded to true in your store
    return { type: APP_DATA_LOADED, payload: data }
}
```

Now, Inside **every component** that relies on the data to be present, you can do something like

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state, ownProps ) => {
    return {
        items: state.app.items,
        loaded: state.app.loaded,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch, ownProps ) => {
    return {
        loadAppData: () => dispatch( loadAppData() ),
    }
}


let MyComponent = (props) => {

    if ( ! props.loaded ) {
        setTimeout( () => {
            props.loadAppData();
        }, 10);
    }


    if ( props.loaded ) {
        return (
            <h1>Data is loaded.</h1>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <h1>Loading data, please wait...</h1>
        )
    }


}
```

**Note:** I have used stateless component as an example here, and am using `setTimeout` to call the `Action` if the data if not loaded.

If you're using `React Class` you can place `props.loadAppData();` within your `componentDidMount` method and it will work.

Comment: thanks for upload, sorry i was typing my sluggish comment, did not see your elaborate response. i wish i could upvote.
anyhow i implmented similar code using redux-thunk. i did series of calls inside the action creator itself. 
however i would be more interested to see your implemntation in middleware. as i said calling cross component actions within actions looks a bit wrong.

Comment: i have created a gist here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c0f2e861f7e4c4746311ef1b728d08ef  can you please take a look. that is my actionCreator.  feels a bit wrong cross-component action dispatches though

Comment: I will add middleware example later, Anyways by middleware i meant `react-router` middleware and not `redux` middleware.. I think `react-router` middleware will be more suitable here.

I use lot of different techniques, I use `react-router` middlware to authenticate users, to load data which are used by many different components and show loading message while data is being loaded and also for certain components, I just redirect the user to the previous page (in your case page1) which loads the data & then in that page i check if the user was redirected and then redirect the user back.

Comment: ok i see,  also have that idea to use entryhook, hovewer i dont want to show the listing page thoug, is redirecting happens smooth, do you prevent url to be flickering,  i want to be able use  bookmark for instance and direcly pick up from there. thanks for your input